# correct way of accessing results from a list from a parent frame in a function call

Tags: r, function, lapply

I'm writing a function, which results I want to write into a list. However, each function call requires to use the results from the previous function call.

So I'm unsure about how to best make sure that each function call (I'm using an `lapply` approach) uses the updated results. i've read about `<<-` and assign, but still don't really now what the cleanest/correctest way would be.

Example:

My naive/wrong approach is:

```
results <- list()

my_function <- function(x)
{
  result <- ifelse(length(results) == 0, 0, results[length(results)])
  2 * x + unlist(result)
}

results <- lapply(1:5, my_function)
```

which returns:

```
[[1]]
[1] 2

[[2]]
[1] 4

[[3]]
[1] 6

[[4]]
[1] 8

[[5]]
[1] 10
```

What I would like to return is:

```
[[1]]
[1] 2

[[2]]
[1] 6

[[3]]
[1] 12

[[4]]
[1] 20

[[5]]
[1] 30
```

So how do I feed the previous results into the function call?

NOTE: the example function is really a very simple example. I know I could probably do a simple cumsum here. But my real life function is way more complicated and not a simple computation of a number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `lapply` only updates `results` after the whole loop is done. Consider the following:

```
my_function <- function(x)
{
  last_res <- ifelse(length(results) == 0, 0, results[[length(results)]])
  print(last_res)
  2 * x + last_res
}
results <- list()
results <- lapply(1:5, my_function)
[1] 0
[1] 0
[1] 0
[1] 0
[1] 0
```

Whilst where we use a regular loop:

```
results <- list()
for(i in 1:5) {
  results[[i]] <- my_function(i)
}
[1] 0
[1] 2
[1] 6
[1] 12
[1] 20
```

---

Now, a better way of achieving this would be to add a `repeats` argument into your function itself.

```
my_function <- function(repeats=5)
{
  result_list <- list()
  for(i in 1:repeats) {
    last_res <- ifelse(length(result_list) == 0, 0, result_list[[length(result_list)]])
    result_list[[i]] <- 2 * i + last_res
  }
  result_list
}

my_function(5)

[[1]]
[1] 2

[[2]]
[1] 6

[[3]]
[1] 12

[[4]]
[1] 20

[[5]]
[1] 30
```

Although the loop-based approach is not strictly global assigning as described in the [sixth circle of Patrick Burns' R Inferno: doing global assignments](https://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf), the second approach is cleaner.

---

Now, if we wanted to dive into the flames, we could use `lapply`:

```
my_function <- function(x)
{
  last_res <- ifelse(length(results) == 0, 0, results[[length(results)]])
  print(last_res)
  results[[x]] <<- 2 * x + last_res
}
results <- list()
results <- lapply(1:5, my_function)
[1] 0
[1] 2
[1] 6
[1] 12
[1] 20
```

Interestingly, using `assign` falls back into the first behaviour

```
my_function <- function(x)
{
  last_res <- ifelse(length(results) == 0, 0, results[[length(results)]])
  print(last_res)
  assign('results[[x]]', 2 * x + last_res,  envir=.GlobalEnv)
}
results <- list()
results <- lapply(1:5, my_function)
[1] 0
[1] 0
[1] 0
[1] 0
[1] 0
```

It seems that even with `assign`, `lapply` only updates the full thing after completion.

This can be explained as from `?assign`

> assign does not dispatch assignment methods, so it cannot be used to
> set elements of vectors, names, attributes, etc.
>
> Note that assignment to an attached list or data frame changes the
> attached copy and not the original object: see attach and with.

Comment: Right, a simple loop could work. I was still hoping that there's a solution with lapply. I mean, if it's technically not possible, then it is what it is and I change to a loop. But not giving up my hope yet.

Comment: using the repeats argument inside the function itself is not to your liking?

Comment: see new edits for an `lapply` solution

Comment: Yes that was I was thinking about. I know the `<<-` is dangerous (saw your post about it in another thread), so I was thinking if there is a more "correct"/safe way with `assign`. But there I'm actually not sure how I could add a specific list element to my results through `assign`.

Comment: see edits: `assign` and `lapply` seem to fall back into the first behaviour. created this question for clarification: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73275077/difference-in-behaviour-between-assign-vs-in-lapply

Comment: Great question, thanks! Because the assign thing is what I hoped for by specifying the environment specifically (so it's a conscious and transparent decision in the code as opposed to `<<-`.