# difference in behaviour between assign vs <<- in lapply

Tags: r

Why do `<<-` and `assign` behave differently when used in an `lapply` loop?

```
my_function <- function(x)
{
  last_res <- ifelse(length(results) == 0, 0, results[[length(results)]])
  print(last_res)
  results[[x]] <<- 2 * x + last_res
}
results <- list()
results <- lapply(1:5, my_function)
[1] 0
[1] 2
[1] 6
[1] 12
[1] 20

my_function <- function(x)
{
  last_res <- ifelse(length(results) == 0, 0, results[[length(results)]])
  print(last_res)
  assign(results[[x]], 2 * x + last_res,  envir=.GlobalEnv)
}
results <- list()
results <- lapply(1:5, my_function)
Error in results[[x]] : subscript out of bounds
```

Note: I know that global assignment is to be avoided, just asking out of curiosity.

Comment: I shoudl probably have read the help function of `assign` earlier: "assign does not dispatch assignment methods, so it cannot be used to set elements of vectors, names, attributes, etc.".

Comment: indeed. that explains it

Comment: Bummer, though.

Comment: You can do this: `.GlobalEnv$results[[x]] <- 2 * x + last_res`

Comment: How would that look like when not assigning in the global environment, but just the parent.frame? I.e. at the level of the function call?